# Generating a PDF with Prawn and Ruby On Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, pdf, prawn

I've been following Ryan Bate's [Railscast tutorial](http://railscasts.com/episodes/153-pdfs-with-prawn-revised) (excellent as always) but have run into an issue that I cannot seem to resolve.

I have my Prawn::Document rendering using static content fine, ie with

```
class PrintPdf < Prawn::Document
  def initialize
    super
    text "Text"
  end
end
```

and in the controller

```
def print
  @vegetaux = Vegetable.all

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html
    format.pdf do
      pdf = PrintPdf.new
      send_data pdf.render, filename: "vegetaux.pdf", type: "application/pdf", disposition: "inline"
    end
  end
end
```

But when I try to pass in my Rails model by adding this

```
pdf = PrintPdf.new(@vegetaux)
```

& this in the pdf object

```
class PrintPdf < Prawn::Document
  def initialize(vegetaux)
    super
    @vegetaux = vegetaux
    text "Text"
  end
end
```

I now get this error message

`no implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer` relating to this line...

```
pdf = PrintPdf.new(@vegetaux)
```

The object @vegetaux seems to be OK though, because in the html reponse I can loop through the individual items and display their contents, ie /print (html) this works fine

```
<ul>
<% @vegetaux.each do |vegetable| %>
  <li><%= vegetable.nom_commun %></li>
<% end %>
</ul>
```

Can anyone help explain why i'm getting this error when I try to create the PDF document?

Thanks!

If I inspect the @vegetaux object with @vegetaux.inspect it returns (test data)

`#<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<Vegetable id: 6, nom_commun: "Basic Flower", famille_id: 1, classe: "Something Else", genre: "Genre", espece: "Espece", origine_geographique: "Earth", cycle_biologique: "normal", racine: "Something else", tige: "another thing", feuillage: "whatevs", fleur: "big skdfhkjs dhfksdhfkj hsdkjfh ksjd hfkjsdh fkjhs...", fruit: "none", graine: "something siomething", modes_de_multiplication_possibles: "lots of things", systemes_de_production_adaptes: "all kinds of things", mise_en_place_de_la_culture: "don't understand the question", calendrier_cultural: "may - july", entretien_de_la_culture: "nope", exigences_edaphiques_ideales: "whatevs", irrigation: "keep it wet", fertilisation: "keep it fertilised", problemes_phytosanitaires_et_protections_adaptees: "none", importance_economique: "very", utilisation: "eat it", diversification: "whatevs", created_at: "2014-11-10 11:37:17", updated_at: "2014-11-19 15:28:08", photo_file_name: "flower.jpg", photo_content_type: "image/jpeg", photo_file_size: 1083468, photo_updated_at: "2014-11-10 11:37:16", exigences_climatiques: "warm & sunny">, #<Vegetable id: 13, nom_commun: "qsd", famille_id: 1, classe: "dsf", genre: "sdf", espece: "sdf", origine_geographique: "", cycle_biologique: "", racine: "", tige: "", feuillage: "", fleur: "", fruit: "", graine: "", modes_de_multiplication_possibles: "", systemes_de_production_adaptes: "", mise_en_place_de_la_culture: "", calendrier_cultural: "", entretien_de_la_culture: "", exigences_edaphiques_ideales: "", irrigation: "", fertilisation: "", problemes_phytosanitaires_et_protections_adaptees: "", importance_economique: "", utilisation: "", diversification: "", created_at: "2014-11-19 14:34:18", updated_at: "2014-11-19 14:34:18", photo_file_name: nil, photo_content_type: nil, photo_file_size: nil, photo_updated_at: nil, exigences_climatiques: "">, #<Vegetable id: 9, nom_commun: "wxc", famille_id: 1, classe: "wxc", genre: "wxc", espece: "wxc", origine_geographique: "", cycle_biologique: "", racine: "", tige: "", feuillage: "", fleur: "", fruit: "", graine: "", modes_de_multiplication_possibles: "", systemes_de_production_adaptes: "", mise_en_place_de_la_culture: "", calendrier_cultural: "", entretien_de_la_culture: "", exigences_edaphiques_ideales: "", irrigation: "", fertilisation: "", problemes_phytosanitaires_et_protections_adaptees: "", importance_economique: "", utilisation: "", diversification: "", created_at: "2014-11-19 14:19:03", updated_at: "2014-11-19 14:19:03", photo_file_name: nil, photo_content_type: nil, photo_file_size: nil, photo_updated_at: nil, exigences_climatiques: "">, #<Vegetable id: 14, nom_commun: "rty", famille_id: 2, classe: "sd", genre: "qsd", espece: "qsdqs", origine_geographique: "", cycle_biologique: "", racine: "", tige: "", feuillage: "", fleur: "", fruit: "", graine: "", modes_de_multiplication_possibles: "", systemes_de_production_adaptes: "", mise_en_place_de_la_culture: "", calendrier_cultural: "", entretien_de_la_culture: "", exigences_edaphiques_ideales: "", irrigation: "", fertilisation: "", problemes_phytosanitaires_et_protections_adaptees: "", importance_economique: "", utilisation: "", diversification: "", created_at: "2014-11-19 17:59:10", updated_at: "2015-04-11 08:50:24", photo_file_name: nil, photo_content_type: nil, photo_file_size: nil, photo_updated_at: nil, exigences_climatiques: "">]>`

Comment: can you post the content or example of `@vegetaux` variable? What would you like to do with it in the model?

Comment: Hi Adam - I've updated my question with the object, it's an Active Record relation

Comment: I'm just trying to loop through the objects and print out all their data formatted well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you override your parent's `initialize` method, calling `super` with no arguments implicitly passes *all* arguments, but since `Prawn::Document`'s initialize takes an options hash (which is different from what you passed), it is trying to extract some keys from vegeteaux.

Call `super` by passing in any arguments the parent class expects, or add the parenthesis to make it obvious you aren't passing anything:

```
class PrintPdf < Prawn::Document
  def initialize(vegetaux)
    super() # I added parentheses here to call Prawn::Document.new() with no args
    @vegetaux = vegetaux
    text "Text"
  end
end
```

Comment: Thank you! That fixes it and your explanation is brilliantly clear.

Comment: @Unixmonkey you saved my bacon. Could not for the life of me work out what was wrong!